# how to get the .tsr file in QTP

Tags: vbscript, qtp

We all know that the .tsr file stores the information of the object repository, and We can load the file to an ObjectRepositoryUtil Object in VBS, then we can do a lot through this object. 
But how can I capture all the widgets in a window and stores into the .tsr file using VBS?
I mean when we do the following in the QTP GUI:

```
Resources->Object Repository Manager->Object->Add Object->
"CLICK THE WINDOW WE WANT TO CAPTURE"->File->Save
```

we actually get the .tsr file of the window and all its components we want to capture.
But how can I do this in VBS, does it have any API?
I look up the document called ObjectRepositoryUtil and find the method GetAllObjects, but it is just not the same thing.
Could anyone solve my problem ? I would really appreciate it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to automate creating an object repository. Usually object repositories are created once and then used for creating tests.

Are you familiar with QTP's **Navigate and Learn** feature, it allows adding all objects from an application while interacting with the application.

Comment: Hi,Motti,I am doing a relevant GUI automate testing research, I want to know the detail of every component in the window under test including the effects of  the component(when click on it, does it pop up a new window or just communicate with the system), I want to take advantage of the QTP API to capture all the component and then find the effect of each component through a program,so I wonder how I can invoke the  relevant API from outside? Thanks.

Comment: @Rain, sorry I'm not familiar with a way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a tool or code that can actually mimic the object capturing capability of QTP, outside of QTP - then no such tool/code is available as of now. However code can be written to retrieve the object properties of an application and that I assume you are aware of.